# How to update .msi installer generated through WiX in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, wix3

thanks for trying to help. I recently started to manage an ASP.NET solution that includes a WiX installer project generated previously. I made changes to the code that I want to include in the new .MSI installer, but I can't find the way for update the installer that was created. This is the project structure:

[Project structure for WiX installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJeG.png)

When I try to compile the entire solution, I realize the WiX project is excluded for compiling with the other projects, but I try to add it to setup properties and it doesn't work, this is the image for that:

[Setup properties for solution I try to complite with installer project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgzgp.png)

Is there any way for build the setup.msi file with my last changes? Hope you all can help me. Thanks. :)

Comment: This might help. https://wixtoolset.org/development/building-wix/. Otherwise, You may use Wix build tools from command-line to generate setup.msi installer.